# Angular2 Listen for addControl() and only then attach valueChanges listener to this control

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a form in Angular2 that is fairly dynamic - namely some of the controls may or may not later be added through `this.form.addControl('some_optional_field', ...)`.

I would like to easily attach a `this.form.controls['some_optional_field'].valueChanges.subscribe()` listener to this specific FormControl ONLY AFTER it was added to the form (when the form is initialized, it doesn't have this optional field attached by default - it's attached at some later arbitrary point of time - by an external logic that does not provide me a callback or an output parameter to hook my login into).

To simplify the question: is there a way to detect when FormControls are added or removed to a given form, so I can react to them accordingly?

Comment: I think you're looking for something that's solved with `this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((some_optional_field_formcontrol: any) => {`

Comment: form.addControl() does not trigger valueChanges on the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `rxjs`:

```
this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.form.get('some_optional_field').valueChanges)
  ).subscribe(value => {

  });
```

This works in current forms of Angular -- I have not back-tested it through all versions.